# problem with react native @hmscore/react-native-hms-location

Tags: react-native, location, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-location-kit

i'm follwing  @hmscore/react-native-hms-location documontation with react native, i'm trying to Continuously Obtaining the Location Information with the requestLocationUpdatesWithCallback() and addFusedLocationEventListener()  functions
i can get the request code from requestLocationUpdatesWithCallback() but the addFusedLocationEventListener() returns nothing , like it dosen't trigered

```
 HMSLocation.FusedLocation.Native.requestLocationUpdatesWithCallbackEx(locationRequest)
  .then((res) => console.log(res))
  .catch((err) => alert(err.message))
  

////////////////////////

HMSLocation.FusedLocation.Events.addFusedLocationEventListener(handleLocationUpdate)


 /////////////////////


const handleLocationUpdate = (locationResult) => console.log(locationResult)
```

any solution for that

Comment: Hello, did you solve your issue? I have same issue, if you solved it can you share how you did it? Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

The location duration depends on the `locationRequest` configuration.

The parameter settings provided in the Demo do not support continuously obtaining the Location Information. You are advised to configure the parameters as follows:

```
    const locationRequest = {
      priority: HMSLocation.FusedLocation.Native.PriorityConstants.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY,
      interval: 60000,    
      numUpdates: 2147483647, 
      fastestInterval: 30000.0,  
      expirationTimeDuration: 2147483647, 
      smallestDisplacement: 0.0,
      language: 'en',
      countryCode: 'en',
    };
```

For details about the parameters, see [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-References-V1/datatypes-0000001057838908-V1#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001057838908__section114821110113515).

Answer (score 0):

From what it seems, this should work. However, there may be permissions you are missing. Please use requestPermission() and hasPermission() functions to request and check if you do indeed have the necessary permissions to actually receive any location information.

You may also want to make a mock location with setMockMode and setMockLocation to make sure your program is working as expected.

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-References-V1/fusedlocation-0000001050043303-V1#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050140366__section1060819319425